# Is there any way to listen to MySQL writing?

Tags: mysql

I wonder if it is possible to listen to writings to a MySQL database from an external program. What I want to do is to listen to changes on one server and send those changes over HTTP to another server.

Comment: What about or why not replication?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions: use replication (if that's possible) or [database triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger).

Answer (score 1):

If feasible, replication (as mentioned by Kris) would probably be your best option.  However, I'll assume that for some reason, replication doesn't work in your use case.  In particular, you mention that you need to send it over HTTP.  I assume you need to do something along the lines of invoke a REST service running on another server over HTTP on each update.  If this is your use case, replication is likely not a viable option.

One option would be a trigger.  I'm not aware of a function available in MySQL that would allow you to directly invoke a REST service from within a trigger.  Also, I'm not sure you would want to, as you'd be increasing latency substantially for each and every database update.  Instead, I recommend that you add a trigger that logs to a local table each time an update, delete or insert takes place on the tables you care about.  This would be sort of an "audit" table.  Then, build a batch process/cron job that reads these tables, and synchronously invokes the external REST service running on another server.

Another option depends upon the language being used to access the database.  For instance, if you're using Java, there are some "proxy" JDBC drivers that can be used that can allow you to inject code into any updates.

Another option would be to configure MySQL to log out to the binary log.  Then, you could parse that binary log, and use a batch/cron process as suggested above, but instead of reading the "audit" tables for updates, you would read the binary log.  Note again, if the databases are exactly the same at both locations, you can setup replication.  If nothing else, you should be able to come up with a process to get the binary logs to the remote server (dependent upon the platforms) where the binary logs can be restored.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html.